# How to capture Slack user data during slash command interaction for Validation purposes?

Tags: slack-api

I have created a Slack application and when the user types a specific slash command then it triggers the backend server API perfectly. However, I want to put some validation checks over here. Every user belongs to some department say, finance which appears on their profile on the Slack application. Now I require some validation to allow only users from a specific department to interact with the Slack application and perform the slash commands. The validation can be done client-side (at the Slack application level before the requests reach my backend APIs) or on the server side.

I have the following queries:-

1. Is there any client-side validation that I can apply in the Slack application to check which department the user interacting with my application belongs to and then put conditions around my slash commands to restrict calling the backend API? If this is possible geat.
2. Or, if client-side validation is not possible in the Slack application, is there a way that I can read the user's information appearing on the profile on Slack and somehow pass that information as POST data to the backend server to put the server-side validation?

I would appreciate your help on this